# Is there a way to be able to use the same ItemsSource of a CollectionView in the behind code and at the same time use it in the ViewModel?

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms

I am making a custom control in which by default, there are certain elements added in the `CollectionView` but I would like to be able to add more elements in the same `ItemsSource` from the ViewModel. Is it possible in any way? I have tried using a `BindableProperty` from the `ItemsSource` in the ViewModel but it only shows the one from the code behind.

CustomControl XAML:

```html
 <CollectionView
                    x:Name="collectionView"
                    Margin="-10,-15,-10,-10"
                    HeightRequest="270"
                    ItemsSource="{Binding Source={x:Reference EditorView}, Path=EmojiItemSource, Mode=TwoWay}"
                    VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Never">

                    <CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
                        <GridItemsLayout Orientation="Horizontal" Span="5" />
                    </CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
                    <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>

                        <DataTemplate>

                            <Label
                                x:Name="Labellabel"
                                Margin="10"
                                FontSize="30"
                                Text="{Binding EmojiSource}"
                                TextColor="#FF000000">
                                <Label.GestureRecognizers>
                                    <!-- <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding Path=BindingContext.EmojiTappedCommand, Source={x:Reference EditorView}}" CommandParameter="{Binding EmojiSource}" />-->
                                    <TapGestureRecognizer CommandParameter="{Binding EmojiSource}" Tapped="TapGestureRecognizer_Tapped" />
                                </Label.GestureRecognizers>

                            </Label>


                        </DataTemplate>
                    </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>

                </CollectionView>
```

CustomControl behind code:

```
public static readonly BindableProperty EmojiItemSourceProperty = BindableProperty.Create("EmojiItemSource", typeof(IList), typeof(Editor));

        public IList EmojiItemSource
        {
            get { return (IList)GetValue(EmojiItemSourceProperty); }
            set { SetValue(EmojiItemSourceProperty, value); }
        }    
        public CustomControl(){    

            ObservableCollection<Emojis> EmojiList = new ObservableCollection<Emojis>();
            collectionView.ItemsSource = EmojiList;

            EmojiList.Add(new Emojis { EmojiSource = Convert.ToString(Emoji.SlightlySmilingFace)  });
            }
```

MainPage:

```html
 <fav1:Editor EmojiItemSource="{Binding EmojiList}"/>
```

Viewmodel:

```
public ObservableCollection<Emojis> EmojiList
        {
            get => emojilist; set
            {
                emojilist = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }    
    public ViewModel(){
        EmojiList = new ObservableCollection<Emojis>();
        EmojiList.Add(new Emojis { EmojiSource = Convert.ToString(Emoji.Kiss) });
      }
```

Comment: Make sure to make the binding mode, Mode=TwoWay, and to also call PropertyChanged for the EmojiList

Comment: When I add Mode=TwoWay, no element of the ObservableCollection is seen, it is all empty. I updated my code with the Mode= TwoWay added and PropertyChanged in EmojiList added too.

Comment: why dont u bind the viewmodel list property to collection view itemsource and then get the collection view itemsource from .cs by using name eg mylistname.itemsource, this would give u a IEnummerable which need to cast using your model, also by keeping it two way if u update your itemsource from .cs it would also get updated in viewmodel

Comment: also the other way is create a object of your viewmodel in .cs and bind that object to your page using bindingcontext and also using same object u can access your EmojiList Eg - ViewModel myviewmodel = new ViewModel();   BIndingContext = myviewmodel;   var mynewlist = myviewmodel.EmojiList

Comment: How can I bind the viewmodel list property to collection view itemsource and get the collection view itemsource from cs? Sorry if this is obvious but I'm new in xamarin forms- Its not binded with the Bindable Property?

Comment: The first option isn't the same that I'm doing in my post?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.Don't set the `itemSource` in both `Xaml` and .`cs`. Remove the codes in code behind and **don't** set it `two-way mode` in xaml.

2.You do not need to create `EmojiList` in the `CustomControl` as what you really want to bind to is the `EmojiList` in ViewModel:

```
    public CustomControl(){    
        //delete all these lines
        //ObservableCollection<Emojis> EmojiList = new ObservableCollection<Emojis>();
        //collectionView.ItemsSource = EmojiList;

        //EmojiList.Add(new Emojis { EmojiSource = Convert.ToString(Emoji.SlightlySmilingFace)  });
        }
```

3.In your `MainPage.xaml`, `fav1:Editor EmojiItemSource=`  should bind to the `EmojiList` in your ViewModel.

So the Binding Source is the `MainPage` ,and the binding path is `BindingContext.EmojiList`(Which means the `MainPage's BindingContext(type of ViewModel).EmojiList`):

```
<fav1:Editor EmojiItemSource="{Binding BindingContext.EmojiList, Source={x:Reference MyPage}}"/>
```

`MyPage` here is the name of MainPage defined in Xaml:

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             mc:Ignorable="d"
             
             x:Name="MyPage"
             
             x:Class="App462.MainPage">
```

Refer: [How to set the BindableLayout.ItemsSource to an ObservableCollection in an other file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62700725/how-to-set-the-bindablelayout-itemssource-to-an-observablecollection-in-an-other/62709191#62709191)

**Update**:

You can only choose one option between binding the itemSource in xaml or set it in code behind.

If you don't want to add default element in ViewModel's EmojiList, you should binding it to another property in ViewMode with the default elements there, next time you update ViewModel's EmojiList, you can also update the property to keep same.

Comment: I don't need to have it all in the ViewModel. What I want to do is add elements of the CollectionView in the code behind the control and, also, be able to add more elements in the ViewModel with the same ItemsSource.

Comment: So what you need to do is access the ViewModel in custom control, Right?

Comment: See the answer in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64415237/how-to-share-view-model-between-pages/64422224#64422224). Make the viewModel you binding in MainPage public and in your custom control, you can access the viewModel.EmojiList, then add/delete elements.

Comment: The problem is that the control is to create a library and be able to use it in other projects, so using the same ViewModel is not a good option for me. Is there no other way to share the ItemSource using Binding?

Comment: Since the control is in other library, how can you `add elements of the CollectionView in the code behind the control`?

Comment: I don't know if I have explained myself well, sorry. I have a project in which I have my custom control which is the CollectionView and in which I want to add the elements mainly. Then I have another project where I add the reference to this first project and use the control. In this second project, I have a ViewModel in which I want to add elements in the CollectionView of the first project. Example: The first collectionView has 5 elements by default, but if a client later wants to add more if they want to, they just have to add them in the ViewModel without modifying the control.

Comment: Yes, my answer is answering your this question. Binding the itemsource of collectionview to property of ViewModel.

Comment: Yes, but you have removed the code where I add elements to the CollectionView from the control. You have removed the "default" elements of my example.

Comment: OK, I understand. Be clear that you can only choose one option of binding the itemSource in xaml or set it in code behind. If you choose to set the itemSource in code behind, then you can't update it later without binding. If you choose binding the itemSource in xaml, the default element should be set in the ViewModel's EmojiList. If you don't want to add  default element in ViewModel's EmojiList, you should binding it to another property in ViewMode with the default elements there, next time you update ViewModel's EmojiList, you can also update the property to keep same.

Comment: So I can only add elements in the CollectionView in one site, in the ViewModel or in the code behind the control, right? Never in both at the same time.

Comment: Binding to another property part in my last comment would solve your problem.

Comment: I have updated my answer and if it helps you, can you please accept it (click the ☑️ in the upper left corner of this answer ) so that we can help more people with same problem:).